# How to merge data into one column from parenthesis

Tags: r, merge, parentheses

I have a data frame like this

```
a<-c("ABC","CDE(b123)","EFG")
b<-c("a123","","c123")
df<-data.frame(A=a,B=b)
df
          A    B
1       ABC a123
2 CDE(b123)     
3       EFG c123
```

I expect to have a new column like this

```
C
a123
b123
c123
```

merge the info from column A inside the parenthesis with column B
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution using regex:

```
df$B <- as.character(df$B)
df$A <- as.character(df$A)
df$C <- df$B

df$C[df$B==""] <- sub(".*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", df$A[df$B==""])

          A    B    C
1       ABC a123 a123
2 CDE(b123)      b123
3       EFG c123 c123
```